# Is there a better functional method to operate on Map[String,List[Int]]

Tags: scala

I'm fairly new to scala and functional programming, and I'm working on a project where I have grocery prices in 30 days and want to apply some analysis over the data that I have.

The data is saved as `map(string, List[Int])`

What I'm trying to do is to get the lowest and highest price for each item, I did it like this and then I have another function that loops over the returned Map and prints it.

```
def f(): Map[String,List[Int]] = {
    var result= Map.empty[String, List[Int]]
    for ((k,v) <- data){
      var low = v.min
      var high = v.max
      result+= (k -> List(low,high));
    }
    result
  }
```

I think this is not the most functional method to do it, can anyone elaborate if there is a way to iterate over the data and return the result without creating an empty map?

Answer (score 3):

The computation does not depend on the keys in any way, so there is no reason to introduce the `k`s anywhere, it's just distracting from the main goal. Just map the values:

```
data.view.mapValues(v => (v.min, v.max)).toMap
```

Also, your signature `f()` doesn't tell anything useful. How do you know what it's doing? If you deleted the body of that function, and were given only `"f()"`, would you be able to unambiguously reconstruct the body? Would the GPT be able to reconstruct the body? Probably not.

Ideally, the signature should be precise enough so you never need to dig into the implementation bodies (and also that you don't actually have to write them). Here is a possible improvement:

```
def priceRanges(itemsToPrices: Map[String, List[Int]]): Map[String, (Int, Int)] =
  itemsToPrices.view.mapValues(v => (v.min, v.max)).toMap
```

Comment: +1. As a follow up, consider using `Range.Inclusive` instead of `(Int, Int)`, since range semantically represents a `min` and `max` together, better than `Tuple2` whose items don't have any inherent meaning.

Comment: @Dylan I considered taking `Range` instead, but once I began wondering whether `Range` is usually inclusive-exclusive or inclusive-inclusive, or something else, I immediately switched back to `(min, max)`

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve this. I think one key aspect is readability, so while the following can be done as a pure one-liner, I think this could be a viable and readable solution:

```
data.map { case (k, v) =>
  k -> Seq(v.min, v.max)
}
```

Feel free to shorten it if you like.

This would also work, but it may be less readable for someone not used to functional programming.

```scala
data.map(kv => kv._1 -> Seq(kv._2.min, kv._2.max))
```

Another thing you may want to consider:
There is nothing that protects the List/Seq in the result type from containing more than two elements. You may want to use a tuple or create a custom type for it.

Answer (score 0):

I love it when people encourage themselves to do functional Scala instead of the imperative style, so congratulations on that.

Returning to your question, I think the easiest way to solve this problem is with the famous `map` function: it takes a function as a parameter which describes how you want to transform each element within the collection. In your case, this function goes from the tuple `(item, values)`, which in your question would be the `(k, v)`, to a new similar tuple, but this time only with the "prices" we are interested in:

```scala
def getLowAndHighPrices(itemsWithPrices: Map[String, List[Int]]): Map[String, List[Int]] =
  itemsWithPrices.map((item, prices) => (item, List(prices.min, prices.max)))
```

You can read the previous `map` implementation as: for each value `(item, prices)`, convert it into the tuple `(item, List(prices.min, prices.max)`. The `map` function literally describes what you want to do, without telling exactly what steps to follow, because map takes care of that for you; that is personally one of the advantages of functional programming.

You can also print the results in a very “functional” way (ignoring the side effects):

```scala
// For demonstration purposes
val allItemPrices: Map[String, List[Int]] =
  Map(
    "Milk" -> List(9, 8, 7, 10),
    "Eggs" -> List(1, 3, 4, 3, 5, 2)
  )


def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    getLowAndHighPrices(allItemPrices).foreach((item, prices) => println(s"$item -> $prices"))

/**
 * Which prints out: 
 * Milk -> List(10, 7)
 * Eggs -> List(5, 2)
 */
```

In this case, `foreach` does something very similar to `map`, with the difference that `foreach` is design to perform side-effects such as printing to the console.

I hope I made myself clear. Good luck on your Scala journey!